# Qt Library not detected by my .Cpp code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-code, vcpkg

I'm using vcpkg to install C/C++ libraries, in my code I need GSL and Qt libraries, when I included them in the properties.json the GSL works fine but Qt cannot be found and therefore cannot run my code.

Problem messages:

"#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (F:\Shared\BLDC_Simulation\GitHub\OpenBLDC\C\open-bldc-csim-master\src\main.cpp)."

"cannot open source file "QtCore""

Comment: Qt will require moc, qic ... You probably want to use the CMake extension

Comment: This guide should help: [https://www.40tude.fr/how-to-use-vcpkg-with-vscode-and-cmake/](https://www.40tude.fr/how-to-use-vcpkg-with-vscode-and-cmake/)

Comment: I'll see what I can do and report back with the results, thank you very much friends.